# What to do when a question-asker is caught trying to pass off a deleted answer as their own work?

Tags: discussion, questions, plagiarism

A relatively-new user with a history of already asking low-quality questions posts what is basically a homework requirement, and asks how it can be done, with no attempt shown.

Users, including myself, chime in that Stack Overflow isn't a do-your-homework-for-you-site, but nevertheless, a few users feel compelled to answer the question anyways, but after pressure from the community, they delete their answers.

This is where it gets weird.

Apparently, the OP saw one of the answers before it was deleted, and then edits their question saying, "i hav done this", and then pastes, *verbatim*, the contents of one of the now-deleted answers.

Now this really torques me off -- yes, this is a community for answering questions, and yes, bad questions should be improved, but the OP was shamelessly trying to pass off someone else's hard work *as their own*, in an effort to get more help.

Fortunately, users with 10K+ rep could still see this, so I pointed out that they had not in fact come up with that code themselves, and rolled their question back.

**My question is:**  I honestly don't know how this should be handled.

Is a roll-back to their original question, along with the comment sufficient enough?  Is this true plagiarism, and something we should flag for moderator attention, a user who is caught trying to pass off someone else's work as their own?  Should I just go get a Coke Zero and move on?

Comment: I don't think they were necessarily *deliberately* trying to pass it off as their own. They may well have genuinely tried the answer that was provided to them. It looks like they didn't fully understand it and had a followup question about it `not sure if I need to put (1, 1000) in range or (2, n+1) is fine? `. Probably I would have just added attribution as in [Giving credit to a user that is no longer involved with the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278935/73226)

Comment: That also sounds to me like they were trying to say that they had *tried to use the code that was in the answer*, not that they were claiming to have written it themselves. I don't think this is plagiarism, I think it's a simple misunderstanding.

Comment: Sounds like you need a Coke Zero

Comment: Maybe a caffeine-free beverage is in order ;-)

Comment: Try a fruit-juice. It is said to help mitigating doubts :) :)

Comment: @ErenorPaz - I do enjoy a good pineapple juice... I shall have to remember that for next time!

Comment: @Peter Mortensen -- is adding a Wikipedia link to Coke Zero really the best use of an edit and/or your time?  What value could that possibly add to the question?  I sincerely don't get why you make edits like this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It sounds like  you made the right choice. Another option that immediately occurred to me was to edit the post to include proper attribution of the code, but that doesn't leave the question in a good state. The OP should have tried the answer and included some explanation of why it still wasn't working (if that was indeed the case) instead of just copy/pasting it to fulfill the "show us your code" requirement. Rolling back the simple copy/paste seems like the best option to me. Escalate to a mod flag if the OP starts an edit war.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that, and thanks for the advice.  I'll keep that other option in mind on the off-chance someone edits their question to included deleted material *and* indicates what didn't work with it :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables You're welcome. If they make any effort at all to show that they're trying to understand the code, I'd give them the benefit of the doubt and just edit in the attribution. It's only in the simplest Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V case that I'd roll back.